# How to convert json string to NSstring with key

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I got the following JSON string in a NSDictionary:

```
{
    "119": 
    {
        "name": "Tidy The House",
        "url": "https://www.website.com"
    }
}
```

How can i get the name of this JSON string?

Comment: Are you trying to get the string "119", "name", or "url" (i.e. the string representations of the keys)? Or are you trying to get the value of the "name" key (as in "Tidy the House")?

Comment: The value of "name". But it's possible that there are more id's like: 119, 120, 121 and so on.

Comment: So you already have a NSDictionary? Did you have a look at the **documentation** of the NSDictionary class? What did you try, where is your problem?

Comment: This is very basic stuff.  Use NSLog to dump what you have in the dictionary (which will be similar to but not identical to the above).  Then read the spec for NSDictionary.  Look especially at `objectForKey`.  Note that what you have above is essentially a dictionary in a dictionary, so you'll have to do two access to "peel" the layers apart.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to iterate over a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284429/is-there-a-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code to get the name from your dictionary

```
for(NSString *key in [YOUR_DICTIONARY allKeys]){
    NSDictionary *dic=[dictionary objectForKey:key];

    NSLog(@"Name = %@",[dic objectForKey:@"name"]);
}
```

Comment: Downvote for a correct answer :-D Whats wrong in the answer ?

Comment: Didn't downvote, though you could use allValues and save yourself a step?