# Swift - How to loop through NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdictionary

Hi I'm currently learning Swift, and I wanted to extract data from a JSON Api, My Swift code looks like this. To be specific, I need to extract each and every key and its value,(for example: print the value of title, cover etc..)

```
//Json request
var error: NSError?
var raw = NSString.stringWithString("http://example.com/MovieAPI/api/v1/movies/")
var api_url = NSURL.URLWithString(raw)
let jsonData: NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(api_url, options: nil, error: &error)
let result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &error)
as NSDictionary
for val in result {
   for (var i=0; i < val.value.count; i++){
       //println(val.value.valueAtIndex(3)) Not Working
   }
}
```

and the structure of my JSON is

```
{
  data: [
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Hunger Games",
        cover: "http://example.com",
        genre: 2
       }
  ]
}
```

Help!

Comment: Well already went through this link and the solution of this link gave me a return value of NIL and an error **Type <AnyObject> does not conform to protocol Sequence**

Comment: So you asked the wrong question. I reopened it. The supposed duplicate was [Iterating through a dictionary in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111627/iterating-through-a-dictionary-in-swift)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here is how you can process a given JSON:

```
let dataArray = result["data"] as NSArray;

print("Data items count: \(dataArray.count)")

for item in dataArray { // loop through data items
    let obj = item as NSDictionary
    for (key, value) in obj {
        print("Property: \"\(key as String)\"")
    }
}
```

**Remarks:**

Remember that you receive parsed objects as `NSDictionary` and when you iterate through the dictionary, order in which you receive properties may differ from the order in the original JSON.

Comment: Thanks! it works! and one more question, does this declaration is right? let result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &error)
as NSDictionary, because it creates memory leak

Comment: What leaks `jsonData` or `result`?

Comment: Hmmm... that is interesting. Can you please share somewhere sample project with stable reproduce of memory leak?

Comment: Now its working without any issues (in between I have updated my xcode to beta 5), I think that resolved my problem.

Comment: Yeah, swift is still beta, so we might face some strange leaks. Happy that problem was solved! :)

Comment: Any way Thank you so much for your help on loop issue :)

Comment: Isn't this conversion a little costy...? I mean a Swift dictionary is internally different from an NSDictionaty - which means that this cast causes a lot of memory moves.

Comment: Try:

if let encodedValue = value.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet()) {
                print("\(key)=\(value)")
            }

Comment: Thanks A lot helped me big time.

Answer (score 4):

Check this piece of code for reference:

```
// MARK: - Firebase
func retrieveData(){
    ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let postDict = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
        let contactList = postDict["contacts"]!
        let user = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser

        let contactArray = contactList[user!.uid]! as! NSDictionary

        for (key,_) in contactArray {

            let contact:NSObject = contactArray[key] as! NSObject
            let firstName:String! = contact.value(forKey: "firstName") as? String
            let lastName:String! = contact.value(forKey: "lastName") as? String
            let company:String! = contact.value(forKey: "company") as? String
            let phone:String! = contact.value(forKey: "phone") as? String
            let email:String! = contact.value(forKey: "email") as? String

            print(contact.value(forKey: "firstName")!)
            contacts.append(Contact(firstName:firstName, lastName: lastName, company: company, phone: phone, email: email))
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })

}
```

It specially gets tricky when you parse the key value into the usable object that is where the NSObject comes to rescue so that you can get the values for key.