# (general) why Alamofire (ios) sort query string parameters

Tags: ios, alamofire

I found in Alamofire code base that they are sorting the query string before they encoded it to the url. Is there any reason behind it?

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/092022fb5b1580e28ce1f1344484e04820c168e0/Source/ParameterEncoding.swift#L92

```
func query(parameters: [String: AnyObject]) -> String {
            var components: [(String, String)] = []
            // why sort the keys?
            for key in Array(parameters.keys).sort(<) {
                let value = parameters[key]!
                components += queryComponents(key, value)
            }

            return (components.map { "\($0)=\($1)" } as [String]).joinWithSeparator("&")
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason is that the traverse order of dictionary is not defined. Therefore the without sorting it is possible the queries can be different even for identical requests. This may cause some undesired behaviour if the parameter order matters (perhaps due to a server bug). It will also make testing harder.

By sorting the parameters, we can guarantee the resulting query string will always be same regardless the OS version and platform.

Comment: yeah, I think you are right, found this too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111627/iterating-through-a-dictionary-in-swift