# How do you iterate through a specific part of a dictionary in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, nested, iteration

I have brought in some JSON, converting it to a dictionary and would like to know if there is an effective way to iterate through a specific level of it ( what with being nested )

For instance, starting with the following:

```
{
    "instrument": {
        "piano": {
            "sounds": {
                "C": "pianoC.mp3",
                "D": "pianoD.mp3",
                "E": "pianoE.mp3",
                "F": "pianoF.mp3",
                "G": "pianoG.mp3",
                "A": "pianoA.mp3",
                "B": "pianoB.mp3",
                "C8": "pianoC8.mp3"
             }
         },
         "guitar": {
             "sounds": {
                 "CMajor": "guitarCMajor.mp3”,
                 "FMajor": "guitarDMajor.mp3",
                 "GMajor": "guitarGMajor.mp3",
                 "AMinor": "guitarAMinor.mp3"
             }
         }
    }
}
```

How would you iterate through the sounds?

Comment: this should get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111627/iterating-through-a-dictionary-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some extensions to `Dictionary`:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func filterValues<T>() -> [T] {
        return values.filter { $0 is T }.map { $0 as! T }
    }

    func filterDictionaries() -> [Dictionary] {
        return filterValues()
    }

    func valuesOfLevel<T>(level: Int) -> [T] {
        var levelItems = [self]
        for _ in 0..<level-1 {
            levelItems = levelItems.flatMap { $0.filterDictionaries() }
        }
        return levelItems.flatMap { $0.filterValues() }
    }

    func dictionariesOfLevel(level: Int) -> [Dictionary] {
        return valuesOfLevel(level)
    }

    func dictionariesOfLevel(level: Int, key: Key) -> [Dictionary] {
        return dictionariesOfLevel(level)
            .flatMap { ($0[key] as? Dictionary) ?? [:] }
            .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
    }

    func valuesOfLevel<T>(level: Int, key: Key) -> [T] {
        return dictionariesOfLevel(level, key: key)
            .flatMap { $0.values }
            .filter { $0 is T }
            .map { $0 as! T }
    }
}
```

In your case you can filter sounds and iterate through them with:

```
let sounds: [String] = dictionary.valuesOfLevel(2, key: "sounds")

for sound in sounds {
  // ...
}
```