# How I can parse JSON file without keys?

Tags: json, swift

I have downloaded JSON file from this url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/master/countriesToCities.json

I got stuck after I parse all JSON file into `let json`

```
 let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/master/countriesToCities.json")!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {

            do{

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

                print (json)
            }catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }

        }
    }

    task.resume()

}
```

The problem is I cant turn to every country and every city because I dont know key->value. How can I turn to every country and city?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating Through a Dictionary in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111627/iterating-through-a-dictionary-in-swift)

Comment: View the Swift Docs https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113   *Iterating Over a Dictionary*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some Swift playground code that does exactly what you want:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let urlStr = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/David-Haim/CountriesToCitiesJSON/master/countriesToCities.json"

let requestURL: URL = URL(string: urlStr)!
let urlRequest: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
    (data, response, error) -> Void in

    let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
    let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

    if (statusCode == 200) {
        do{
            let json:[String:[String]] = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! Dictionary
            for (country, cities) in json {
                print(country)
                for city in cities {
                    print("City in \(country): \(city)")
                }
            }


        }catch {
            print("Error with Json: \(error)")
        }

    } else {
        print("Other status: \(statusCode)")
    }
}

task.resume()
```

They key is knowing the format of your data, in this case a dictionary containing `String` keys and array of `String` values.  When you declare your json variable, cast it to what it actually is:

```
let json:[String:[String]] = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! Dictionary
```

Comment: Its works. Thank you very much. Now its clear for me

Answer (score 0):

In this response you have all you need to find all data about country and cities.

You have response that is dictionary `[String:[String]]` type.

Example:

Part of the response :

```
let json = ["Eritrea":["Asmara",""],"Cuba":["Havana","Habana","La Habana","Matanzas","Villa","Bayamo","Cienfuegos","Santiago de Cuba","HolguÃ­n","Ciego de Ãvila","Pinar del RÃ­o","Sancti SpÃ­ritus","CamagÃ¼ey","Las Tunas","GuantÃ¡namo","Varadero"],"Saint Helena":["Tristan Da Cunha","Jamestown"],"Christmas Island":["Flying Fish Cove"],"Ethiopia":["Addis Ababa","Awasa","Jijiga"],"British Indian Ocean Territory":[""]]
```

So if you would like to fetch all country names just do like this:

```
let keys = Array(json.keys)
```

If you would like to fetch cities for example for **Eritrea** do it like this:

```
let cityes = json["Eritrea"]
```