# How to iterate over a dictionary of objects, and their keys

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Swift and Firebase.  I'm currently storing my firebase snapshot objects in a global dictionary.  The idea is to then filter those objects based on the value of one or more of their keys.

For example, the pendingFilter() might return all those objects whose "pending" key is equal to true, and ignore the rest.

Array is created like this:

```
var array = [NSDictionary]()
```

All objects are appended as AnyObject.

My current dictionary looks something like this:

```
[{
    accepted = false;
    cancelled = false;
    id = "1";
    pending = true;

}, {
    accepted = false;
    cancelled = false;
    id = "2";
    pending = true;

}, {
    accepted = true;
    cancelled = false;
    id = "3";
    pending = false;
}]
```

In my filter function, I know I can iterate over each item with a for-in, but how would one go about then filtering by key values for the objects themselves?  Is there a preferred Swifty way of doing this?  I know about (key, value) in item, but this seems strictly geared towards dictionaries and not objects.

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating Through a Dictionary in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111627/iterating-through-a-dictionary-in-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter` to have only dictionaries with the value of the key `pending` set to `true`.

```
var pendingFilter: [NSDictionary] {
    return array.filter { $0.value(forKey: "pending") as? Bool == true }
}
```

Comment: Great, straightforward solution.  This works.  Thank you!

Comment: @sharedev Hold up a sec. If you are actually storing the values in the Array as AnyObject, this answer won't work. Value of type Any does not have a member .value, which makes sense as key:value pairs are Dictionary structures and not Any structures. You should consider storing your data as a Class or Structure which would give you direct access to the the properties as suggested in this answer.