# Iterating through dictionary keys of decoded JSON in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I received excellent help in my previous question on how to set up my foundational JSON model. I am able to parse any values I want.

While I can parse any values I want, I am only able to access symbols or other values separately using dot notation.
`btcSymbol = rawResponse.btc?.symbol`
`ethSymbol = rawResponse.eth?.symbol`

I found other questions about iterating through dictionaries like [Iterating Through a Dictionary in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111627/iterating-through-a-dictionary-in-swift) but these examples are basic arrays and not multi-nested dictionaries using Swift's new protocols.

I want to be able to:
1. Iterate through the JSON and extract **only the symbols** from the CMC API.
2. Have a model where I am able to iterate all values of each currency separately so that I can later send those values to a table view for example.
`BTC | name | symbol | marketCap | MaxSupply`
`ETH | name | symbol | marketCap | MaxSupply`

Would restructuring my already existing model be the best solution? After my model is built would a standard for in loop or map be better?

JSONModel

```
struct RawServerResponse : Codable {
enum Keys : String, CodingKey {
    case data = "data"
}
let data : [String:Base]
}

struct Base : Codable {
enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case id = "id"
    case name = "name"
    case symbol = "symbol"
}

let id : Int64
let name : String
let symbol : String
}

struct Quote : Codable {
enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case price = "price"
    case marketCap = "market_cap"
}

let price :  Double
let marketCap : Double
}

extension RawServerResponse {
enum BaseKeys : String {
    case btc = "1"
    case eth = "1027"      
}
var btc : Base? { return data[BaseKeys.btc.rawValue] }
var eth : Base? { return data[BaseKeys.eth.rawValue] }

}

extension Base {
enum Currencies : String {
    case usd = "USD"
}
var usd : Quote? { return quotes[Currencies.usd.rawValue]}
}

struct ServerResponse: Codable {
let btcName: String?
let btcSymbol: String?

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let rawResponse = try RawServerResponse(from: decoder)

    btcSymbol = rawResponse.btc?.symbol
```

JSON

```
{
"data": {
    "1": {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "website_slug": "bitcoin", 
        "rank": 1, 
        "circulating_supply": 17041575.0, 
        "total_supply": 17041575.0, 
        "max_supply": 21000000.0, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 8214.7, 
                "volume_24h": 5473430000.0, 
                "market_cap": 139991426153.0, 
                "percent_change_1h": 0.09, 
                "percent_change_24h": 2.29, 
                "percent_change_7d": -2.44
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least I'd recommend to map the `data` dictionary to get the `symbol` as key rather than the `id`, by the way if the keys are *camelCaseable* and you pass the `.convertFromSnakeCase` *key decoding strategy* you don't need any coding keys, for example

```
struct RawServerResponse : Codable {
    var data = [String:Base]()

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case data }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let baseDictionary = try container.decode([String:Base].self, forKey: .data)
        baseDictionary.forEach { data[$0.1.symbol] = $0.1 }
    }
}

struct Base : Codable {
    let id : Int64
    let name : String
    let symbol : String
    let quotes : [String:Quote]
}

struct Quote : Codable {
    let price : Double
    let marketCap : Double
}

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let rawResponse = try decoder.decode(RawServerResponse.self, from: data)
    for (symbol, base) in rawResponse.data {
        print(symbol, base.quotes["USD"]?.marketCap)
        // ETH Optional(68660795252.0)
        // BTC Optional(139991426153.0)
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```