# How could I handle dictionary in Swift 3

Tags: ios, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I am beginner, working with firebase I loaded a dictionary from firebase database which is as follow:

```
["bkayfdbUpJXDEpVF8WWl362amct2": {
    Email = "s@s.com";
    Name = "abce";
    Username = "abce";
}, "4gQHKfSAHmXU5q7rOP45OeN8yrz1": {
    Email = "f@f.com";
    Name = "abcq";
    Username = "abcq";
}, "OI0ppw6jSeW4Ao2nRff8Yq9uk162": {
    Email = "a@a.com";
    Name = "asd";
    Username = "asd";
}, "zbNvoAmunpVUkeQtt09r2RLaSqv1": {
    Email = "d@d.com";
    Name = "abcs";
    Username = "abcs";
}]
```

I want to print username present in this key "4gQHKfSAHmXU5q7rOP45OeN8yrz1" I tried following code but it's not working

```
let refContacts = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("allUsers")        
refContacts.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in            
    if let contactsDic = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
        print(contactsDic[0]["4gQHKfSAHmXU5q7rOP45OeN8yrz1"].["Name"]])                
    } else {                           
    }            
})
```

Further I want to store all usernames in an array how it can be done?

Comment: `contactsDic[0]` with a `Dictionary`, does that really work? You can iterate a dictionary (for keys/values), and in your cases, values will be a Dictionary. I'd recommend that over any other Swift method. An explicit loop should be done then because you are a beginner and that's basic algorithmic.. See there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111627/iterating-through-a-dictionary-in-swift

Comment: Your data is `[[String: Any]]`. Mind the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few questions rolled into one so I will address them with code. The following code could be shortened; I left it a bit verbose to show the flow and a I put a little error checking in as well which could be improved.

Note that I substituted keys of uid_0 and uid_1 for brevity.

```
//a class to store the firebase data in an array
class ContactClass {
    var key = ""
    var email = ""
    var name = ""
    var username = ""

    convenience init(fromSnapshot snap: DataSnapshot) {
        self.init()
        self.key = snap.key

        if let dict = snap.value as? [String: Any] {

            let e = dict["Email"] as? String ?? ""
            let n = dict["Name"] as? String ?? ""
            let u = dict["Username"] as? String ?? ""

            self.email = e
            self.name = n
            self.username = u
        }
    }
}

var contactArray = [ContactClass]() //array to hold data read from Firebase

//read all of the contacts, create a class for each and store in an array
//then print their keys and filter the array for a specific key and print the name
func contactAction() {
    let refContacts = self.ref.child("allUsers")
    refContacts.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        for child in snapshot.children {
            let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let contact = ContactClass(fromSnapshot: childSnap)
            self.contactArray.append(contact)
        }

        for c in self.contactArray {
            print(c.key) //prints uid_0 and uid_1
        }

        let filteredContactResult = self.contactArray.filter { $0.key == "uid_1"}

        if let firstResult = filteredContactResult.first {
            let name = firstResult.name
            print(name) //prints asd
        }
    })
```

There are probably 100 other ways to do these same tasks; this method will maintain ordering and make it pretty easy to filter the read in data.

Oh - you are using an older version of Firebase (due to FIRDatabase) so it would be good to upgrade your Firebase to a current version as well.

The self.ref used in the above code is a class var that points to my Firebase.