# SwiftUI: How can I read a specific document in Firestore?

Tags: ios, database, firebase, swiftui

So I have a “Users” collection in Firestore, and I want to read one of the documents.

The document I want to read has a UserUID as its Document ID, so my question is how can I read that document?

Would really appreciate the help.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```swift
Button(action: {
    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) =>  \(document.data())")
            }
        }
    }
}) {
    Text("Read Data From DataBase")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you're really asking a SwiftUI question, or just a Firebase question, so I'll address both parts.

In terms of getting a specific document from Firebase, you'll want to use a more specific query than `getDocuments`.  Specifically, you can use `document()` and pass the ID as a parameter:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(userID).getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
        let fieldValue = document.get("myFieldName") as? Int
        let fieldValueType2 = document.data()["myFieldName"] as? Int
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

(this sample code is based on the Firebase documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#swift

Having no knowledge about how your data is structured within your document, it's tough to say *exactly* what to do next, but if you wanted to store a property of it in a variable to be available in your view, you could set a @State variable:

```
struct MyView : View {
  @State var myData : String = ""
  
  ...
  //in your firebase callback:
  myData = someDataFromTheFirebaseDocument
}
```

You will most likely find that storing your networking logic (eg talking to Firebase) inside your `Button` callback has some limitations and pitfalls. Might want to consider something like an `ObservableObject` that handles these calls and then has a `@Published` property you can access from your view.

A limited example of this would be (*note: just a conceptual example -- not tested code*):

```
struct MyView {
  @ObservedObject var firebaseConnector = FirebaseConnector()

  var body : some View {
    VStack {
      Button(action: { firebaseConnect.apiCall() }) {
        Text("Press me")
      } 
      Text("Firebase data: \(firebaseConnector.dataToDisplay)")
    }
  }
}

class FirebaseConnector : ObservableObject {
  @Published var dataToDisplay : String

  func apiCall() {
    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(userID).getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        self.dataToDisplay = dataDescription
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer it really helped. But how can i extract a specific field in a document, without knowing the value of that specific field? @jn_pdx

Comment: I've updated my first code sample with an example of how to query a certain field.  document.data() returns a `[String:Any]` dictionary so you can get a field value with that or by using `document.get()`.  If the answer has helped you, please consider upvoting/accepting

Comment: Once again, thanks it worked perfectly. Another question i have is, after retrieving a document, how can i loop over all the field values and do something with them? Like if had stored images, how would i loop over them, and then display each image? @jn_pdx

Comment: `document.data()` will give you a `Dictionary` of type `[String:Any]`.  You can iterate over it using something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111627/iterating-through-a-dictionary-in-swift

Comment: So i looked at the stack link, but im not sure how to iteration over the Values in the doc. Would it be possible for you to show me? Would really appreciate  it @jn_pdx

Comment: @Nick `document.data().forEach { (key, value) in ... }` or `document.data().values.forEach { value in ... }` or `document.data().keys.forEach { key in ... }`

Comment: @Nick if you need more than that, go ahead and create another question here on SO so that it can be answered separately instead of in the comments.  I'd be happy to keep helping, but that would be the preferred method

Comment: Sry for the late answer, but I have created a separate question and would appreciate it if you would take a look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65962758/swiftui-how-can-i-find-a-specific-but-deep-buried-document-in-firestore-without @jnpdx

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share my solution with you guys.
I created a checkPassword function to check if the user password is correct.
***notice:** This is a vers.1 Solution - you should not (!!) implement a password check like this, it is not save for a productive version.*

```
func checkPassword(username : String, password : String)
{
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    let docRef = db.collection("databaseUser").document("\(username)")
    docRef.getDocument{(document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"

            //Example output: Document data: ["password": test, "username": Test, "email": Test]
            print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")

            //To understand with what you are working with...
            //document.data Output: Optional(["password": test, "username": Test, "email": Test])
            print("\(document.data())")

            //now you have the fields "password", "username" and "email". You can access every field with...

            let fieldVal = document.get("password") as! String
            print("Password is: \(fieldVal)")
            //same with.. let fieldValTwo = document.get("username") as! String will return the next field.

        } else {

            print("username does not exist") //username check is before that with a separated function.
        }
    }
}
```

}