# How can I find a specific but deep buried document in Firestore without knowing the collection/documet name?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having some trouble with Firestore and hope you can help out.

So I have setup my Firestore like following:

I have a "Users" collection with a bunch of documents called "User1" and "User2" etc.

and inside each of these documents there is another collection called "Houses"

and inside this there is a bunch of documents called "House1" and "House2" etc.

and these all contain the same fieldNames but with unique fieldValues.

So my question is, suppose I know that one of these House documents has the fieldValue "WaterHouse" in it but I dont know in which User document and House Document. How can i then parse through all the User Documents and the House documents and get the document that contains the fieldValue "WaterHouse"?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to know the name of the collection(s) to search. If you don't know the collection name, there is no way to find documents.

But you don't need to know the entire path to the collection. So if you know what document exists in `Houses`, but you don't know what `Users` document it is under, you can use a [Collection Group Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to search across all collections named `Houses`.

Comment: So just to be sure i understand it right, if I know the name of a house document i can find out the name of the User document? @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: Yes, from the `QueryResult` you get back, you get a `DocumentSnapshot` and then you can `docSnapshot.reference.parent.parent` to get the the parent document of the subcollection that the document is in.