# Making func to share text with shareButton in iOS

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I'm new at programming at all, trying making app with country's info (capital, language, currencies etc.).
For now all working except one thing. I want make button to share text info about country. And at this place start's troubles, I can't write method to share my currencies and language info.  I write func to capture one currency from each country, but I don't understand how to iterate through my currencies and languages, to get all values if country have more than 1 currency and language. I understand how to do it in my tableView method, using indexPath for this, but can't understand how do it this at another function. Sorry for my English :) It's not my native language.
I parse JSON from RestCountries. This is my struct to parse JSON:

```
struct Country: Codable {
    let name: Name
    let cca2: String
    let capital: [String]?
    let population: Int
    let currencies: [String: Currency]?
    let languages: [String: String]?
}

struct Name: Codable {
    let common: String
    let official: String
}

struct Currency: Codable {
        let name: String?
        let symbol: String?
    }
```

This is my DetailViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UITableViewController {
    var country: Country!
    let flag = "Flag"
    let general = "General"
    let currency = "Currency"
    let language = "Languages"
    var currencyText = ""
    lazy var languages = country.languages?.sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }
    lazy var sectionTitles = [flag, general, currency, language]
    lazy var currencies = country.currencies?.sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        title = country.name.common
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(shareTapped))
        
       
        }
       
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionTitles.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionTitles[section]
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch sectionTitles[section] {
        case flag:
            return 1
        case general:
            return 4
        case currency:
//            How make to return proper number's of rows??
            return currencies?.count ?? 0
        case language:
            return country.languages?.count ?? 0
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch sectionTitles[indexPath.section] {
        case flag:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Flag", for: indexPath)
            if let cell = cell as? FlagCell {
                cell.flagImageView.image = UIImage(named: country.cca2.lowercased())
            }
            return cell
            
        case general:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Text", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Common country name: \(country.name.common)"
            case 1:
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Official country name: \(country.name.official)"
            case 2:
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Capital: \(country.capital?[0] ?? "Unknown")"
            case 3:
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Population: \(country.population) people"
            default:
                return cell
            }
            return cell
            
            case currency:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Text", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            if let (code, currency) = currencies?[indexPath.row] {
                let currencyCode = code
                let currencyName = currency.name ?? ""
                let currencySymbol = currency.symbol ?? ""
                cell.textLabel?.text = "Code: \(currencyCode), Currency: \(currencyName), Symbol: \(currencySymbol)"
            }
            return cell
            case language:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Text", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            if let (_, language) = languages?[indexPath.row] {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Language: \(language)"
            }
            return cell
        default:
            break
        }
        return UITableViewCell ()
    }

    @objc func shareTapped () {
        currenciesText()
        let shareFlag = UIImage(named: country.cca2.lowercased())
        let shareText = """
General
\(country.name.common)
\(country.name.official)
\(country.capital?[0] ?? "")
\(country.population)
Currencies
\(currencyText)
"""
        

        let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareFlag!, shareText], applicationActivities: [])
        vc.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
    func currenciesText () {
//        How to make this work if country have more than 1 currency?
        if let (code, currency) = currencies?[0] {
            let currencyCode = code
            let currencyName = currency.name ?? ""
            let currencySymbol = currency.symbol ?? ""
        currencyText = "\(currencyName) (\(currencyCode), \(currencySymbol))"
    }
        }
    
    }
```

I'm totally lost in all this loops, this must be the way use for-in, but all things I try Xcode don't like :))) Please help! :)

Comment: If you want to get all the currencies or languages of a country in an array form, you can do something like `country.currencies.values` and loop over the array, this is the simplest way  - this will give you an array of all your currencies for that country. This is an operation you can do with dictionaries: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/values - Ofcourse there are also more sophisticated and complex ways to do this with lesser code.

Comment: Hopefully this link will work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111627/iterating-through-a-dictionary-in-swift

Comment: @ShawnFrank Thanks! That helped! Now everything works as it should :)