# How to get key and value in separate variables when both are unknown?

Tags: ios, objective-c, object

I have kind of weird requirement but I think there should be a way to get it done.
I have something like this:

```
{
        65645556616154 = 1615460475;
}
```

I want "65645556616154" and "1615460475" in separate variables or in same array with different keys or indexes using Objective C.

expected output:

```
a = "65645556616154";
b = "1615460475";
```

Is this possible without knowing key or value ?

Comment: Not entirely clear - are you parsing text and want to extract the key and value from something that looks like that?

Comment: I am parsing json and it looks like that and want to get both values in separate variable or in an array so I can access both separately.

Comment: Enumerate the dictionary, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284429/is-there-a-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary

Comment: Thanks @vadian it is what I needed. Thanks for saving my life ;)